# facebook scraper don't see anything

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mytaste.net%2Fr%2Fpeanut-butter-chocolate-overload-brownies-jordn%25C3%25B6tssm%25C3%25B6r-och-choklad-overload-brownies-151263063.html) tells me that

> Object at URL 'http://www.mytaste.net/r/peanut-butter-chocolate-overload-brownies-jordn%C3%B6tssm%C3%B6r-och-choklad-overload-brownies-151263063.html' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.

And when i see what facebook sees it's just blank.

I have a `og:title` and this is my source:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="549606838459936">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:image" content="//cdn.mytaste.org/i?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdailyinakitchen.files.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F04%2Fimg_4418.jpg&amp;w=1200&amp;h=628&amp;c=1">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="628">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="myTaste.net">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mytaste.net/r/peanut-butter-chocolate-overload-brownies-jordn%C3%B6tssm%C3%B6r-och-choklad-overload-brownies-151263063.html">
<meta property="og:title" content="Peanut butter Chocolate Overload Brownies – Jordnötssmör och Choklad “overload” Brownies">
<meta property="og:description" content="Then I made the batters, added in Reese’s pieces in the chocolate batter, and chopped peanut butter cups to add on top">
<meta property="og:locale" content="sv_SE">
```

Dose anyone have a clue to why that is?

Comment: Make sure your content is actually retrievable under the IPv6 address the debug tool shows. Facebook prefers IPv6 over v4 - this often leads to problems when v6 is not configured properly.

Comment: the server can handle IPv6... one weird thing is that http://www.mytaste.net/about works but http://www.mytaste.net/ doesn't

Comment: Check the server logs after a scrape, to see if the request actually reaches your server, and how it gets answered.